# jQuery function to check if background page fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I was wondering if it's possible to use the `$().ready` function to test if another page is fully loaded.

Here I'm talking about a newsfeed updater, where the function will send a `POST` request to a background php page to update the database, and then, using ajax, the newsfeed will reload to grab new data.

```
function send_data(){
    var head = $("#headline").val();
    var news = $("#news").val();
    var info = '&headline='+head+'&news='+news; //update string
    $.ajax({
        url: 'recieve_update.php', //updating php file
        type: 'POST',
        data: info                 //data string
    }); 

    $().ready(function() {
        $("#newsfeed").load("load_news.php"); //reload the newsfeed viewer
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the callback function of `$.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'recieve_update.php', //updating php file
     type: 'POST',
     data: info,                 //data string
     success: function(){
        $("#newsfeed").load("load_news.php"); //reload the newsfeed viewer
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe something alone these lines would be what you're looking for.  Straight from the jQuery source.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
  $(this).addClass("done");
});
```